# How to determine the quality of an image based on major key terms of Image Processing using OpenCv / scikit-image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

**TL;DR**: What are the major key components (and how to calculate them) of an image to find the quality of an image and detect the problem in the image.

I have multiple problems with my data. A few of them being Blur, Extremely Dark, Extremely Bright Image, Camera Flash on Image, Uneven Brightness / Intensity.

I have found a few Solutions to the problems such as:

**Blur**: Finding the threshold of images using [Laplace Variance](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/) and [Fast Fourier Transformation](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/06/15/opencv-fast-fourier-transform-fft-for-blur-detection-in-images-and-video-streams/)

**Camera Flash**: By [Seprating the background from foreground and finding the bright pixels and STD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933790/robust-algorithm-to-detect-uneven-illumination-in-images-detection-only-needed)

Apart from these, I have written some functions to find some basic values about image. **Please correct the methodology if wrong**:

```
def overall_brightness(image:str, method:str='LAB', normalize:bool=True)->float:
    '''
    Find the brightness value of an image
    args:
        image: Path of Image
        method: Using any of the colorspace (GRAY, LAB, HSV)
        normalize: Whether to return the normalize value between 0-1
    '''
    image = cv2.imread(image)
    
    if method == 'LAB':
        L, A, B = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB))
        if normalize:
            L = L/np.max(L)
        return np.mean(L)
    
    elif method == 'HSV':
        H, S, V = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
        if normalize:
            V = V/np.max(V)
        return np.mean(V)
    
    elif method == 'GRAY':
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        if normalize:
            gray = gray / np.max(gray)
        return np.mean(gray)

def overall_contrast(image, method:str='RMS')->float:
    '''
    Find the overall contrast
    args:
        image: Image string or Path of Image
        method: Standard Deviation (RMS) method or the alternate channel method using (LAB or YUV) colorspace
    '''
    image = cv2.imread(image)
    
    def alternate(channel:np.ndarray)->float:
        '''
        Alternate method to find the contrast
        '''
        min_ = np.min(channel)
        max_ = np.max(channel)
        contrast = (max_ - min_)/(max_ + min_)
        return contrast
    
    if method == 'RMS':
        image = cv2.imread(image)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        return gray.std()
    
    elif method == 'LAB':
        L, A, B = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB))
        return alternate(L)
        
    elif method == 'YUV':
        Y, U, V = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV))
        return alternate(Y)
```

Some of the samples of Image are as:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How we can measure the quality of something is subjective.. will depends of the situation and the environment conditions

Comment: @FreddyDaniel can you give me some common terms for that?